# notification daemon configuration trouble

Tags: 12.04, notification, notify-osd

I am using ubuntu 12.04, and I have somehow got a notification daemon with dumb looking graphics. (I actually purged unity and installed gnome. I also tweaked certain settings from compiz-configuration-settings-manager. I am not sure which one so these might have caused this.)

This is how my notifications look like currently -

[image]

I want it to be like this one -

[image]

However, a strange behaviour I observe is that when I log into my guest seesion, I have the latter good-looking notification daemon. Clearly, the problem must be with some settings/configurations of the notification daemon for my main user.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: This old question, especially the comments on the answer actually helped work around a bug with the ubuntu 16.04 upgrade process https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome-flashback/+bug/1639602. Thx for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses Notify-OSD (the latter in your guest account), and Gnome uses notification-daemon.  I would try to install Notify-OSD alongside Gnome in order to get the notifications you'd like, or use Shell OSD to edit the Gnome based notifications.

Comment: I have purged unity, so even in guest account I have gnome. Also, I have both things installed - notification-daemon and Notify-OSD, I just want to make sure that gnome uses Notify-OSD. How do I do that?

Comment: I purged notifcation-daemon and now gnome uses notify-osd! Thank you! I just have one small problem now - The notifcation daemon's background color is changed for some reason (its perfect in the guest session). It would be really helpful if you could help me fix that.